# How can i edit a specific data in room database? - Kotlin

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I get the respose from api and stored it in the room to display the results. I have a edit button in my detail fragment. if i edit any name in detailFragment it need to update the characterName at Room Database. how can I do that?
PC : I'm new to android development

**DetailActivity.kt**

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDetailBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDetailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        supportActionBar?.hide()



        binding.editBtn.setOnClickListener {
            showEditDialog()
        }

        // Get the HpProperty object from the intent extra
        val hpProperty = intent.getSerializableExtra("hpProperty") as? HpProperty

        binding.character.text = getString(R.string.character_name, hpProperty?.character)
        binding.nickName.text = getString(R.string.character_nickname, hpProperty?.nickname)
        binding.hogwartsHouse.text = getString(R.string.character_house, hpProperty?.hogwartsHouse)
        binding.interpretedBy.text = getString(R.string.character_actor, hpProperty?.interpretedBy)

        Glide.with(this)
            .load(hpProperty?.image)
            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .transform(CircleCrop())
            .into(binding.imageView)
    }

    private fun showEditDialog() {
        val hpProperty = intent.getSerializableExtra("hpProperty") as? HpProperty
        binding.character.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.characterEdit.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.editBtn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.tickBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.characterEdit.setText(getString(R.string.character_name, hpProperty?.character))

        binding.tickBtn.setOnClickListener {
            updateDatabase()
        }
    }

    private fun updateDatabase() {
        binding.tickBtn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.editBtn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.characterEdit.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.character.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface HpPropertyDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAll(hpProperties: List<HpPropertyEntity>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM hp_properties")
    fun getAll(): List<HpPropertyEntity>

    @Update
    fun update(hpProperty: HpPropertyEntity)
}
```

**if I edit the name and clicked the tick Button, it need to edit the room database and also it need to be updated on the recycler view that shows characters name.**

Answer (score 0):

Edit the database equates to an UPDATE.

There are two ways to update using Room. You can either use a function that is annotated with the `@Update` annotation (the convenient way) or you can specify an `@Query` with an UPDATE SQL statment.

- there are other ways of issuing an UPDATE statement e.g. via an `@RawQuery` but these are not usually used.

The former identifies the row to be updated according to the value or values that make up the primary key of the table from the object or objects passed to the function. Thus the value or values of the primary key cannot be changed.

The second method is more flexible but typically a little more convuluted/complex, but can allow the primary key column(s) to be updated.

So **check to see that you are setting the correct value(s) for the field(s) that make up the primary key of the `HpPropertyEntity`** passed to the update function (assuming that is what you are eventually invoking to perform the update).